# Dynamically adding data into LineChart JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, task, linechart

I want to set some values into LineChart but Ive got an error: Duplicate series added, or NPE (I try to `clear` my series list, calling `retainAll` but nothing helps) In my controller class Ive stored my `chart` instance

```
 public static void loadToJSON(LocalDate startDate,LocalDate endDate,Controller controller) {



    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override protected Integer call() throws Exception {
             double MIN_VAL=Double.MAX_VALUE;
             double MAX_VALUE=Double.MIN_VALUE;
            XYChart.Series<String,Number> series = new  XYChart.Series<String,Number>();


            for (LocalDate date = startDate;
                 !date.isEqual(endDate.plusDays(1));
                 date = date.plusDays(1)) {

                String formattedDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                URLConnection urlCon = null;

                String baseURL="http://api.fixer.io/";
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(baseURL+formattedDate+"?symbols=PLN,EUR");
                    urlCon = url.openConnection();

                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream());
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    ExchangeRate jsonObject = mapper.readValue(in, ExchangeRate.class);

                    if(MIN_VAL>jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN"))
                        MIN_VAL=jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN");
                    if(MAX_VALUE<jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN"))
                        MAX_VALUE=jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN");
                    in.close();

                      series.getData().clear();
                    series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String,Number>(formattedDate,jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN")));
         controller.chart.getData().add(series);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        controller.messageBox.setText("Best exchange rate : "+MIN_VAL + " \nWorst exchange rate : "+MAX_VALUE);
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
```

Comment: Can you make the question more precise? [Edit] it so that it will compile (fix the method declaration, add matching try block for the extra catch, or remove the catch, etc etc etc). State exactly what exception you get from the code that is posted, include the stack trace and identify the line in the code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: I have function that get the values form api with 200ms intervals. I want to put the obtained data into LineChart (the plot in function updating whenever getting another value from api), but whenever I try to update my  LineChart Ive get error: Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added

Comment: So can you please post *that* code, along with the exception it generates, instead of the code you have posted in the question (which does nothing of the sort)?

Comment: The exception is saying you are adding the same series to the chart multiple times. Your code clearly doesn't do that (and doesn't "get the values from api with 200ms intervals": it gets one set of values, once).

Comment: Okay i trimmed my code before to make it simpler and focus only of that issue, but as you want I paste it all

Comment: Well you "trimmed" out the cause of the exception. If you are going to simplify code before you post it, you need to run the simplified version to make sure it actually demonstrates the problem you are trying to fix. I recommend you read how to create a [MCVE] - it will make it easier for you to get help in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeatedly adding the same series to the chart, by calling

```
controller.chart.getData().add(series);
```

inside the loop. This will cause the exception you describe (" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Duplicate series added").

Instead you should add the series once, before the beginning of the loop, and then add data to it inside the loop.

You are also violating the threading rules of JavaFX, because you are modifying the chart from a background thread. The UI can only be accessed from the JavaFX Application Thread. So you should wrap the calls that modify the chart (and the series, once it is added to the chart) in `Platform.runLater(...)`:

```
public static void loadToJSON(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, Controller controller) {

    Task<Integer> task = new Task<Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            double MIN_VAL = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            double MAX_VALUE = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();

            Platform.runLater(() -> controller.chart.getData().add(series));

            for (LocalDate date = startDate; !date.isEqual(endDate.plusDays(1)); date = date.plusDays(1)) {

                String formattedDate = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));

                URLConnection urlCon = null;

                String baseURL = "http://api.fixer.io/";
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(baseURL + formattedDate + "?symbols=PLN,EUR");
                    urlCon = url.openConnection();

                    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(urlCon.getInputStream());
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    ExchangeRate jsonObject = mapper.readValue(in, ExchangeRate.class);

                    if (MIN_VAL > jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN"))
                        MIN_VAL = jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN");
                    if (MAX_VALUE < jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN"))
                        MAX_VALUE = jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN");
                    in.close();

                    // Not sure why you are doing this?
                    // series.getData().clear();


                    Plaform.runLater(() -> 
                        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(formattedDate, jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN"))));

                    // controller.chart.getData().add(series);

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(200);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Platform.runLater(() -> 
                    controller.messageBox.setText("Best exchange rate : " + MIN_VAL + " \nWorst exchange rate : " + MAX_VALUE));
            return null;
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right I should paste all the code.Your solution helped, but not 100% correct (ive got an error that series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(formattedDate, jsonObject.getRates().get("PLN")))t should be called on FX application thread). but it worked and I try solve that issue too

Comment: @Expiredmind It *is* being called on the FX Application thread. You wrapped it in `Platform.runLater(...)` as I did in the solution? And you should *not* paste all your code: you should write a [MCVE], as I said in the comments below your question.